# Do not resize Table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have large URL(without spaces) in one of my Table(html table element) cell which resize table. I do not want to resize table, what property should I set to break URL into new line?

**HTML**

```
<table class="ui-grid" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="MainContent_gvStatistic" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <caption>Statistic (Last 50 conversions)</caption>
    <tbody><tr>
        <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Result</th>
            <th scope="col">Api</th>
            <th scope="col">IP</th>
            <th scope="col">Source</th>
    </tr><tr>
        <td style="width:200px;">12/16/2011 3:23:59 PM</td>
        <td align="center" style="width:50px;">True</td>
        <td align="center" style="width:100px;">Web2Pdf</td>
        <td align="center" style="width:100px;">::1</td>
        <td style="width:200px;">http://a1.quickcatchlabs.com/phototemplates/football_blimp_1.html?i_url=http%3A//lh3.ggpht.com/yf5lVBB_WNBvBHT1HoIzY1SG0-PY5zRCobP3vBacuSk9N346F7CeAIRSFOltR6ZC1-yf-MNKAcAd7bAZ_A%3Ds612-c&amp;i_name=Patriots%20%20vs%20Redskins&amp;i_venue_name=Gillette%20Stadium%20&amp;i_venue_address=Foxborough%20%2C%20MA&amp;d_Score_0=34&amp;d_Score_1=27&amp;d_Period_0=Final&amp;p_name_0=Patriots%20&amp;p_name_1=Redskins</td>
    </tr>   
    </tbody></table>
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-grid { width: 100%; margin: 5px 0 10px 0; border: solid 1px #eeeeee; border-collapse: collapse; }
.ui-grid td { padding: 2px; border: solid 1px #eeeeee; }
.ui-grid td b { font-weight: bold; }
.ui-grid th { padding: 4px 2px; color: #fff; background: #000000; border-left: solid 1px #eeeeee; text-align: center; }
.ui-grid .alt { background: #fcfcfc; }
.ui-grid .pgr { background: #424242; }
.ui-grid .pgr table { margin: 5px 0; }
.ui-grid .pgr td { border-width: 0; padding: 0 6px; border-left: solid 1px #666; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; line-height: 12px; }
.ui-grid .pgr a { color: #666; text-decoration: none; }
.ui-grid .pgr a:hover { color: #000; text-decoration: none; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most practical approach is to add the tag `<wbr>` after each acceptable break point, such as “/”, “?”, and “&” (maybe also “=”). This tag has been supported by browsers since the early days; it is not included in any HTML specification (though it is proposed to be standardized in HTML5), but it works practically always and has no know drawbacks.

Since this is about a URL in text, the breaks should appear at natural points of division, not arbitrarily. Various style guides (like The Chicago Manual of Style) have their own recommendations, but the simple break point rules mentioned above should be acceptable on all accounts and normally suffice.

There’s some more info on my page on [word division in HTML and related matters](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html).

Answer (score 8):

Add the following to your css

```
table-layout:fixed
word-wrap:break-word
```

The following site has a good walk through of this
http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200704/how_to_prevent_html_tables_from_becoming_too_wide/

i modified your code a little and this is what works for me hopefully it will help you

```
 <html>    
<div id="wrap">
        <div id="content-primary">
<table class="table" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="MainContent_gvStatistic" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <caption>
                Statistic (Last 50 conversions)
            </caption><tbody>
        <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Date</th><th scope="col">Result</th><th scope="col">Api</th><th             scope="col">IP</th><th scope="col">Source</th>
                </tr>
        <tr>
                <td style="width:100px">12/16/2011 3:23:59 PM</td><td align="center"                                style="width:50px;">True</td>
        <td style="width:100px">Web2Pdf</td>
        <td style="width:100px">::1</td>
        <td style="width:100px">http://a1.quickcatchlabs.com/phototemplates/football_blimp_1.htmli_url=ht%3A//lh3.ggpht.com/yf5lVBB_WNBvBHT1HoIzY1SG0-PY5zRCobP3vBacuSk9N346F7CeAIRSFOltR6ZC1-yf-MNKAcAd7bAZ_A%3Ds612-%20%2C%20MA&amp;d_Score_0=34&amp;d_Score_1=27&amp;d_Period_0=Final&amp;p_name_0=Patriots%20&amp;p_name_1=Redskins</td>
            </tr>   
        </tbody></table>
</div>
</div>


</html>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen,print,projection">
    @import '/css/lab.css';
#wrap {
    width:60em;
    margin:2em auto;
}
#content-primary {
    float:left;
    width:60%;
}
#content-secondary {
    float:right;
    width:36%;
}
table {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #f00;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
th,
td {
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:left;
}
    </style>
```

Comment: If I put table-layout:fixed on my table the TD style="width:100px;" is ignored in my table.

Comment: can you post what you have for your table and css?

Answer (score 1):

You can try several things:

1. add the CSS3 property `word-wrap: break-word;`
2. You can put a div inside your table cells. Nothing within that div will stretch out the table cell.
3. `max-width` css property

Comment: Had a problem with table cells auto resizing. Used max-width and that put a stop to it. I also had to use overflow:hidden to achieve the desired effect, but this answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

Surround the URL in a containing `div` inside the `td`. Apply `word-wrap:break-word; width:200px` to the `div` container. The `div` container is for the benefit of IE. In Chrome, for instance, the styles can be applied directly to the `td`.

`word-wrap` is non-standard, however, it has excellent browser support, including IE6+.

Here is an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3dx/KeA3c/).

Comment: word-wrap:break-word do not work, Url still resize my table and cell

Comment: You will need to apply this to an inner `div` container for IE to render this correctly. I've updated my answer.